# response 302 location to variable in volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm using volley with callback interface. I'm send post request to server and server response 302 status code. How to set location in responsed header to variable string type? Then i want start new activity with full screen webview with this location.

this code in volley classes send requests:

```
public StringPostRequest(Context context, String url, Map<String, String> params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.url = url;
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new NukeSSLCerts());
    }

public void getString(final VolleyCallback callback) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url ,
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    req = response;
                    callback.onSuccess(req);

                }
            }
            ,new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(final VolleyError error){
                final int status = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                // Handle 30x
                if(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM == status || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
                    final String location = error.networkResponse.headers.get("Location");
                    callback.onSuccess(location);

                }
            }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return params;
        }
    };
    mQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
public interface VolleyCallback{
    void onSuccess(String req);
}
```

In Main activity i'm creating Map for Post Request.

```
 Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("foo", "bar");
    params.put("foo1", "bar1");
    params.put("foo2", "bar2");

    StringPostRequest getRedirectUrl = new StringPostRequest(this,url,params);
    getRedirectUrl .getString(new StringPostRequest.VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String req) {
            Log.d("reqInMainact", req);
            RedirectUrl[0] = req;
        }
    });
    return RedirectUrl[0];
```

But Location in response header not write to RedirectUrl[0] ((
Help me please

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide your code

Comment: ok ) Updated question

Comment: What exactly are you returning `RedirectUrl[0];` to? You can't return from a callback. You do the action **within** the callback

Answer (score 0):

> But Location in response header not write to RedirectUrl[0]

I'm sure it did, but you wrote your asynchronous code as if it was synchronous.

Make whatever method that has `return RedirectUrl[0];` be `void`, and try this

```
StringPostRequest getRedirectUrl = new StringPostRequest(this,url,params);
getRedirectUrl.getString(new StringPostRequest.VolleyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String req) {
        Log.d("reqInMainact", req);

        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("URL",req);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

> Then i want start new activity with full screen webview with this location

More details:

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: I'm try this. But In **String req** on **public void onSuccess(String req)** get html page with needs Location. How get Location Url ?

Comment: I don't know what that means?

Answer (score -1):

I doing easy ))) I'm start webview with old url and get redirect in WebView ) Thanks all and sorry